# how to mark the html and body tag in chrome developing tool

Tags: html, css

I build a fixed sidebar, with the bootstrap framework and i added some styles by my one in a different file. I noticed in the developing tool from google that when i go with the mouse over the html or body tag, it will not mark them (blue), like it should be, i also noticed that when i remove the `position:fixed` attribute from the sidebar div, it will mark them correctly, but not when i let the fixed attribute on the div container.

```
<div class="pulse-menu">
    <div class="menu-profile clearfix">

    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-grid"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="icon-grid"></i> Models</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="icon-grid"></i> Kunden</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="icon-mustache"></i> Buchhaltung</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="icon-mustache"></i> Mitarbeiter</a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.pulse-menu {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 19.286em;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1050;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-profile {
  width: 270px;
  height: 230px;
  background: url(../img/media/menu_bg.svg) ;
background-size: 270px 221px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.pulse-menu>nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pulse-menu>nav>ul>li {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:rgb(89, 89, 90);
  display:block;;
  font-size:13px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:20px;
  list-style-image:none;
  list-style-position:outside;
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  text-align:left;
  width:200px;
}

.pulse-menu>nav>ul>li>a {
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:rgb(89, 89, 90);
  cursor:auto;
  display:block;
  font-size:13px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:13px;
  list-style-image:none;
  list-style-position:outside;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding-bottom:13px;
  padding-left:25.008px;
  padding-right:25.008px;
  padding-top:13px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:left;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.pulse-menu>nav ul>li>a [class^=icon-]{
  padding-right: .9375rem;
  width: 1.875rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

i did not change any styles for the body or html attributes inside the default bootstrap.css and do not include any by my own.

[image: Here is a screen when i click on the html tag]

[image: and thats when i click on the sidebar, it will mark them as blue]

[Demo](http://prototyp.awesom-media.de)

Comment: It is marking it blue, but as you can see it shows a height of 0 so nothing is visible. For a fixed position you need to set a height and width

Comment: what a question! I'm still suprised  `:-O`

Comment: think it's time for a break.  Yep, i realized it now too. Sorry guys

Comment: It is not a Google Chrome Developer Tools problem - the body tag has a height of 0 (so doesn't have a blue rectangle) because the `absolute` and `fixed` [CSS position types](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) make the element be positioned outside the parent `body` element so don't add to its width and height.

Comment: thx for the answer, fixed it already. But thank you